# Is it possible to precompile jsp into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, precompile

The title is pretty straightforward.

I would like to know if there is any possibility of seeing the compiled jsp (the servlet generated) directly into eclipse. Without deploying onto any server.

Comment: This is still server-specific. Which one are you using?

Comment: Any server is okay as long as I can make sure the jsp code is correct. I know that with tomcat I can deploy from eclipse and check the result of the compilation in some kind of work directory. But I would like a fully integrated into the ide solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work with JSPs, I suggest to buy [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/) since it can compile JSPs and show you problems (compile errors, etc) in the editor. Eclipse 3.6 also works but JSP support is much better in MyEclipse.

If you just want to compile the JSPs, then have a look at [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). With the help of the [JSPC Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jspc/), you can compile the JSPs into Java code and then add this source folder to your project.

For completeness: There is an ancient [Tomcat plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html#A3) along with the [UQBar Extension](http://uqbar-tomcat-xt.sourceforge.net/download.html). That will configure Tomcat to compile the JSPs into a work folder in your project *as you use them* (i.e. this is not precompilation but the usual on-the-fly-JSP-compilation).

Comment: I'm not interested in buying MyEclipse. :)

Thanks for the info about JSPC plugin, I didn't try it, but it seems that it is the best I can have for the moment.

Comment: @David: When working a lot with JSPs, MyEclipse is worth its money. I also feel odd about buying OSS but $65 is less than I spend on comic books every month.